# Object reference not set to an instance of an object errors when using CreateUserWizard

Tags: c#

The error - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" occured when I hit the "Next' button of my CreateUserWizard controls. I had checked through my codes that I did not leave any of my variables null. but i still can't solve this errors.

```
 Source Error: 

    Line 29:         object UserGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;
    Line 30: 
    Line 31:         DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString()); //this is the line that caused the error
    Line 32: 
    Line 33:         DataSource.Insert();

This is my html code file: 

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
            OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" CreateUserButtonText="Next" 
            FinishCompleteButtonText="Create User" Height="330px" 
            Width="512px">
            <WizardSteps>

                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep2" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User Information</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username:</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Username is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password:</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Password is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Email:</td>
                              <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" />
                                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" 
                                      ErrorMessage="Email required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Question:</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Question" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" ControlToValidate="Question" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Question is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Answer:</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Answer" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" ControlToValidate="Answer" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Answer is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                 <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password"
                                        ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."></asp:CompareValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep0" runat="server" Title="User Details">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Billing Information</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name:</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustName" />
                                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" ControlToValidate="CustName"
                                     ErrorMessage="Name is required."  />
                                     </td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>Contact Number:</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustNum"  />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" ControlToValidate="CustNum"
                                     ErrorMessage="Contact num is required."  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>Role:</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="CustRole" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="16px" 
                                    Width="123px">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Bride</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Groom</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator20" ControlToValidate="CustRole"
                                     ErrorMessage="Role is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>                
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Status:</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="CustStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    Height="17px" Width="121px">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Status A</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Status B</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Status C</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CustStatus"
                                    ErrorMessage="Status is required."/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Partner&#39;s Name:</td>
                              <td class="style1">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PName"  />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="PName"
                                     ErrorMessage="PName is required."  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Partner Email:</td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PEmail"  />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                PRole:
                            </td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="PRole" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="16px" 
                                    Width="123px">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Bride</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Groom</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" ControlToValidate="PRole"
                                     ErrorMessage="PRole is required." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Wed Date:
                            </td>
                            <td class="style1">
                                <cc1:DatePicker ID="WedDate" runat="server" CalendarDate="" 
                                    TextCssClass="" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" ControlToValidate="WedDate"
                                    ErrorMessage="Wedding date required"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:WizardStep>

                <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    Complete</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Your account has been successfully created.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Button ID="ContinueButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Continue" Text="Continue" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>


                       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertExtraInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1 %>"
                        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [UserDetails] ([UserId], [CustName], [CustNum], [CustRole], [CustStatus], [PName], [PEmail], [PRole], [WedDate]) VALUES (@UserId, @CustName, @CustNum, @CustRole, @CustStatus, @PName, @PEmail, @PRole, @WedDate)"
                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1.ProviderName %>">
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustName" Type="String" ControlID="CustName" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustNum" Type="String" ControlID="CustNum" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustRole" Type="String" ControlID="CustRole" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustStatus" Type="String" ControlID="CustStatus" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PName" Type="String" ControlID="PName" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PEmail" Type="String" ControlID="PEmail" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PRole" Type="String" ControlID="PRole" PropertyName="Text" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="WedDate" Type="String" ControlID="WedDate" PropertyName="Text" />
                        </InsertParameters>

                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>

        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
        <br />
    </div>

This is the code behind: 

    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox UserName=
        (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");

        SqlDataSource DataSource =
        (SqlDataSource)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("InsertExtraInfo");

       MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(UserName.Text);

        object UserGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;

        DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());  //the error lies at here

        DataSource.Insert();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger?  The stack trace attached to the NullReferenceException should tell you the location from which the exception was thrown.  Set a break point near that location and debug through VS to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had checked through my codes that I did not leave any of my
>   variables null. but i still can't solve this errors.

You have not checked all your variables, otherwise this error would not be occurring.

Have you checked your DataSource to ensure the SqlDataSource is being found? The InsertParameters property of the DataSource to ensure that it is not null? The UserGUID to ensure that it is not null?